# Increasing the height of the HeaderView in ListView on OverScroll

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am working on a feature for one of the project, where i have a image in the ListView header, And the content bottom to the Header. When i force scroll  the ListView, though there is not space to scroll, i need to increase the height of the header so that it displays the bottom part of the image in the header view, when i release the scroll, the scroll should go to the actual height where it is earlier. Can you please help me on this on how to do, i am trying multiple approaches but not getting the expected behavior.

Comment: show what you have tried so far ..

Comment: I am using the bellow mentioned class for the parallax effect,
https://github.com/ygorbarboza/AKParallax-Android
But i need to customise the my scroll behavior a lot still

Comment: The header should stick to top edge always, and when the user scrolls down, i should increase the height of the header, and when the user releases the scroll , the header height shd resize to its actual position like 
  [this](https://i.imgsafe.org/a085facb6b.png)
 and 
  [this](https://i.imgsafe.org/a09500e4ba.png)

Comment: when i place the image in ScrollView, its not working, (i need this because, i need to animate-scroll the image also alone within the scroll view initially when i launch the screen)